# How to get the dynamic values in shared view pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit Profile", "Index", "Profile")
```

Instead of "Edit profile" text I want the UserName of the user. This action link is in shared pages of the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code using [Identity.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
@Html.ActionLink(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, "Index", "Profile")
```

Answer (score 0):

If `username` is in `session` then do as :

```
@Html.ActionLink(Session["Username"].ToString(), "Index", "Profile")
```